# Dropdown button outside container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown button using the follwoing code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I have this button inside a div container, the problem is that when I click the button the dropdown list appears inside the div borders.

I need it to appear outside the div, top most of all items in the page, how to do that?

Please see this image:

[image]

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Please see the image in the edit, I need the dropdown to be topmost

Comment: Is that content in an iframe or an overflow div?

Comment: Its in an overflow div

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `z-index:1000` for your dropdown

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="z-index:1000">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you.